# Linq- Finding the Same Record Total

Tags: linq

In the image below, the total number of times which business is viewed each day is kept. What I want to do is to find the total number of views belonging to the same id number. For example, I want to find the total view value of records whose businessId is 400.

[Database Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWydq.png)

Comment: Are you using EF? You should check the documentation of [.Count()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-7.0).
You can add a lambda expression like `.Count(i => Id == 400);`

Comment: This is a specification, not a question. Where are you stuck trying this? Also, when turning this into a real question, please also show the class model and tell which ORM you're using (+ version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the work, you may need to adapt some stuff indeed :

```
var totalViewsByBusinessId = records
    .GroupBy(r => r.businessId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        BusinessId = g.Key,
        TotalViews = g.Sum(r => r.views)
    });

int businessId = 400;
var totalViews = totalViewsByBusinessId
    .FirstOrDefault(g => g.BusinessId == businessId)?.TotalViews ?? 0;
```

With that, you will get the total amount of views for each business. Then you will just need to use a where to see the total views of the wanted business.